# AWS and centOS assign private IP

Tags: amazon-ec2, centos7, whm

I have a AWS ec2 instance with centOS 7 and WHM installed and need to be able to set eth0 with a static private IP.  Right now it is using DHCP.
Elastic IP has been assigned and everything works as expected but I have been advised by cPanel that not having a static IP set will cause issues.

Here is the current ifcfg-eth0:

```
# Created by cloud-init on instance boot automatically, do not edit.
#
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
DEVICE=eth0
HWADDR=12:fd:fc:7c:55:cc
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Ethernet
USERCTL=no
```

I tried changing the file to:

```
BOOTPROTO=static
DEVICE=eth0
HWADDR=12:fd:fc:7c:55:cc
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Ethernet
IPADDR=172.31.75.251
PREFIX=20
GATEWAY=172.31.64.1
DNS1=8.8.8.8
DNS2=8.8.4.4
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=no
```

After restarting networking everything works fine but when I reboot it reverts back to the original file.  I see that it says that it's created by cloud-init so I assume this is what is doing it?

I tried looking up info on cloud-init but could not find related to my issue.

Anyone know what I need to do so I can get a static IP set?

Answer (score 3):

Finally found the solution!  So for anyone that has the same problem the fix is pretty simple.

1. Edit /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 with appropriate parameters to set as static.
2. Edit /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg and at the end of the file add:

   ```
   network:
    config: disabled
   ```

   That will stop cloud-init from overwriting your network config.

Comment: This isn't how EC2 is designed to work.  The instance's private address *is always static*, it just happens to be assigned by DHCP... but it never changes.  You also should not use Google's DNS servers unless you have a specific reason to do so.  The DNS servers in your account are the base +2 of your CIDR (probably 172.31.0.2) and 169.254.169.253 (always the same).  Also, cloud-init is your friend, and disabling features is not usually advisable.  With this disabled, you can't create an AMI of your machine and launch a second one like it while the original one still exists, even if stopped.

Comment: It may not be designed to work that way but it is what WHM requires.  So far I have not seen any issues.